# How to get close button/icon back in Eclipse views

Tags: eclipse

I have recently upgrade my Eclipse installation from 2020-06 (4.16) to 2020-09 (4.17) using the [recommended way](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F). After restart and while opening the same workspace I use for years, the [close button/icon is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGG3H.png) for some views when they are selected

This seems to be a [known problem](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#remove-gifs). However, closing the view and reopening it (as suggested on that page) doesn't work for me - the icon/button is still missing. I have also tried closing the view, restarting Eclipse, re-opening the view, and also while starting Eclipse using the `-clean` argument. This didn't help either.

Interestingly enough, for some views the icon/button is [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKkyw.png).

What else can be done to get the icon/button back?

Comment: It is even worse: You can't any longer close the views by a middle-click. Note that the news page you link to talks only about *icons* of the individual views - it's not talking about the close button & close functionality that totally disappears after migration. For me, the only working way was to reset the perspective as answered by @greg-449.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reseting the Perspective worked for me - Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue for me. Though, it cost me about half an hour to make screenshots of all my customised perspectives and restore them manually, sigh.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as [Eclipse bug 565946](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565946), which currently (2020-10) is still in status *NEW*.